# Регулярные выражения php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как правильно составить регулярные выражения PHP, чтобы скрипт отдал ответ при обнаружении ПЕРВЫХ трех чисел - 789? Тоесть, к примеру, человек вводит 789111111 (ПЕРВЫЕ ТРИ НУЖНЫХ МНЕ ЦИФРЫ) - у меня срабатывает код нужный код.

Comment: ну так, не могу найти...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^789/', '789111111')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: по-идеи, то, что нужно)

Comment: Это срабатывает только на первые 3 цифры, верно? тоесть если будет: 77777789 - код не сработает?

Comment: да. если нужно любые из 7/8/9, то регексп будет таким: /^[789]{3}/